# How do I make a post request? I use OkHttp? no server response

Tags: android, okhttp

I need to post a message to server.
- MediaType :  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

So, I used FormEncodingBuilder class for making body.
I wrote this code.

```
Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(SCHEME)
            .encodedAuthority(HOST)
            .appendPath("v3")
            .appendPath("svc")
            .appendPath("auth");

    FormEncodingBUilderformBody = new FormEncodingBUilder()
            .add("name", data.getName())
            .add("gender", data.getGender())
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(uri.build().toString())
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = mHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        String body = response.body().string();

        return body;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApiException(0, e.toString());
    }
```

but server didn't read parameter.
So, server request parameter's value.
How do I make message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to set charset.
but FormEncodingBuilder class use only MediaType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
So, you can make new class like FormEncodingBuilder.

```
public class OkHttpFormBuilder {

private MediaType CONTENT_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
private final StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();


public OkHttpFormBuilder() {
}

public MediaType getCONTENT_TYPE() {
    return CONTENT_TYPE;
}

public void setCONTENT_TYPE(MediaType CONTENT_TYPE) {
    this.CONTENT_TYPE = CONTENT_TYPE;
}

public OkHttpFormBuilder add(String name, String value) {
    if(this.content.length() > 0) {
        this.content.append('&');
    }

    try {
        this.content.append(URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")).append('=').append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        return this;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var4) {
        throw new AssertionError(var4);
    }
}

public String getContent()
{
    return this.content.toString();
}

public RequestBody build() {
    if(this.content.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Form encoded body must have at least one part.");
    } else {
        byte[] contentBytes = this.content.toString().getBytes(Util.UTF_8);
        return RequestBody.create(CONTENT_TYPE, contentBytes);
    }
}}
```

After you make formbody using this class, try send to server